# Keypress Function for two pages

Tags: jquery

I have a page which when a link is clicked, I use the `ajax` call to load up its content in a given `div`. Now my problem is this, In pages of `link-1` and `link-2` I have this code in each

```
<!-- THIS IS FOR THE FIRST LINK-->
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    x = document.getElementById("show_photo<?php echo $id; ?>");
    y = document.getElementById("full_photo<?php echo $id; ?>");
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        if(y.style.display == "block"){
            $("#full_photo<?php echo $id; ?>").css('display', 'none');
        } else if(x.style.display !== "block"){
            $("#all_photo<?php echo $id; ?>").css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
});

<!-- THIS IS FOR THE SECOND LINK-->
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    x = document.getElementById("show_photo");
    y = document.getElementById("full_photo");
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        if(y.style.display == "block"){
            $("#full_photo").css('display', 'none');
        } else if(x.style.display !== "block"){
            $("#all_photo").css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
});
```

The `id`s are different because `page-1` runs in a DB query loop. Now If `link-1` is clicked and the page loads up, the code functions normal but if `link-2` is clicked an its page loads up, the code doesn't function again. It says `Cannot read property 'style' of null` in my `console.log` so I found out that when I load up `link-1` the code is executed and when I load up `link-2` even though the `link-1` page isn't visible anymore the code still runs in the page. So when I click the `ESC` key it can't find the `id`s from the `page-1` so I give the error in the `console.log`. Please is there any way I can run both codes in the two different pages without both of them colliding with each other?

Comment: try like this 
<!-- THIS IS FOR THE SECOND LINK-->
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    x = document.getElementById("show_photo");
    y = document.getElementById("full_photo");
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
     if(x){
      if(x.style.display !== "block"){
             $("#all_photo").css('display', 'none');
         }
     }
     if(y){
      if(y.style.display == "block"){
             $("#full_photo").css('display', 'none');
         }
     }
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this
--------------
code
------
    <!-- THIS IS FOR THE SECOND LINK-->
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        x = document.getElementById("show_photo");
        y = document.getElementById("full_photo");
        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            if(x){
                if(x.style.display !== "block"){
                    $("#all_photo").css('display', 'none');
                }
            }
            if(y){
                if(y.style.display == "block"){
                    $("#full_photo").css('display', 'none');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```